# Animation UIImage shortcut?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage

Hey guys first question posted!

I just started with Obj-C and I am doing my first animation. My animation consist of 60 images of 2 seconds but I am finding a bit tedious to state every single image within my code.

```
 self.backgroundImageView.animationImages = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00001"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00002"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00003"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00004"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00005"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00006"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00007"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00008"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00009"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00010"],
    ....
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"CB00060"],
```

Is there any shortcut for this?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 61; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CB%05ld", (long)i];
    //init your image with the name here.
    //...
}
```

Format integer with `%ld` and `05` means the width of the format string is 5, if length less than 5, insert leading 0.

Comment: "CB%05ld" Could you explain this notation. I understand why you are using it but just to see the mechanics behind it.

Comment: format integer with %ld, 05 means the width of the format string is 5, if length less than 5, insert leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int a = 1; a <= 60; a++) {
    [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CB%05i", a]]];
}

self.backgroundImageView.animationImages = array;
```